Compose - Scrollable list with a scalling (resizeable) header
I'd like to achieve this behaviour with compose.

So basically it's a nested scrollable list with a header, when the list isn't scrolled the header is expanded at maximum height (e.g. 264.dp), and when the list starts to scroll, it scrolls over the header but respect to a minimum height of header to be still visible (e.g. 115.dp).
I have tried so many things but still couldn't achieve this behaviour. The last thing I tried is a complex solution with Modifier.swipeable and nestedScroll in a motion layout which works almost fine but first swipeable is deprecated, and second, it's really complex. Isn't a better way of doing this?
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
) {
    val swipingState = rememberSwipeableState(initialValue = SwipingStates.Expanded)
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val heightInPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { maxHeight.toPx() }
        val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
            object : NestedScrollConnection {
                override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                    val delta = available.y
                    return if (delta < 0) {
                        swipingState.performDrag(delta).toOffset()
                    } else {
                        Offset.Zero
                    }
                }

                override fun onPostScroll(consumed: Offset, available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                    val delta = available.y
                    return swipingState.performDrag(delta).toOffset()
                }

                override suspend fun onPostFling(consumed: Velocity, available: Velocity): Velocity {
                    swipingState.performFling(available.y)
                    return super.onPostFling(consumed, available)
                }

                private fun Float.toOffset() = Offset(0f, this)
            }
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .swipeable(
                    state = swipingState,
                    thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.5f) },
                    orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                    anchors = mapOf(
                        0f to SwipingStates.Collapsed,
                        heightInPx to SwipingStates.Expanded
                    )
                )
                .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
        ) {
            val computedProgress by remember {
                derivedStateOf {
                    if (swipingState.progress.to == SwipingStates.Collapsed) {
                        swipingState.progress.fraction
                    } else {
                        1f - swipingState.progress.fraction
                    }
                }
            }
            val startHeightNum = 264.dp
            MotionLayout(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                start = ConstraintSet {
                    val header = createRefFor("header")
                    val column = createRefFor("body")
                    constrain(header) {
                        this.width = Dimension.matchParent
                        this.height = Dimension.value(startHeightNum)
                    }
                    constrain(column) {
                        this.width = Dimension.matchParent
                        this.height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                        this.top.linkTo(header.bottom, 0.dp)
                        this.bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom, 0.dp)
                    }
                },
                end = ConstraintSet {
                    val header = createRefFor("header")
                    val column = createRefFor("body")
                    constrain(header) {
                        this.height = Dimension.value(115.dp)
                    }
                    constrain(column) {
                        this.width = Dimension.matchParent
                        this.height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                        this.top.linkTo(header.bottom, 0.dp)
                        this.bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom, 0.dp)
                    }
                },
                progress = computedProgress,
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .layoutId("body")
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(bgColor)
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    ) {
                        // list items
                    }
                }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .layoutId("header")
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(startHeightNum)
                ) {
                    // header item
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Would one of these work? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/components/app-bars#scroll

No I don't think app bar is what I need. The important thing about this is that the list scrolls "over" the header not beneath it. Also the header is constant, so it doesn't move, shrink or disappears. It's like upon a scroll gesture, the list first moves up without scrolling until a certain position, and then start scrolling.

I finally found the solution
val headerHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { HEADER_HEIGHT_MAX.toPx() }
val minHeightPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { HEADER_HEIGHT_MIN.toPx() }
val headerHeight = remember { mutableStateOf(headerHeightPx) }
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            val delta = available.y
            if (delta < 0 && headerHeight.value > minHeightPx) {
                val newHeight = headerHeight.value + delta
                headerHeight.value = newHeight.coerceIn(minHeightPx, headerHeightPx)
                return Offset(0f, delta)
            }
            return Offset.Zero
        }

        override fun onPostScroll(consumed: Offset, available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            val delta = available.y
            if (delta > 0 &&
                scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 &&
                scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset == 0
            ) {
                val newHeight = headerHeight.value + delta
                headerHeight.value = newHeight.coerceIn(minHeightPx, headerHeightPx)
                return Offset(0f, delta)
            }
            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }
}
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
) {
    Column {
        HeaderView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(with(LocalDensity.current) { headerHeight.value.toDp() })
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        )
        LazyColumn(
            state = scrollState,
        ) {
            items() // or item
        }
    }
}


